# Strange fluidsynth assertion ( 'settings != NULL') result

Tags: c, debugging, glib

the small example program below is giving me an assertion error ('settings != NULL' failed) and I can't understand why it thinks the settings structure pointer is NULL.

File test.c:

```
#include <fluidsynth.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    fluid_settings_t* settings = new_fluid_settings();
    fluid_synth_setint(settings, "synth.polyphony", 128); //assertion error
    delete_fluid_settings(settings);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: gcc test.c -lfluidsynth.

I've tried printing the address returned by new_fluid_settings() but it seems a valid address to me.

So I've searched through the fluidsynth 1.1.5 source code and find out the line 1213 of the file utils/fluid_settings.c :

```
fluid_return_val_if_fail (settings != NULL, 0);
```

But fluid_return_val_if_fail is just a simple macro for calling GLib's g_return_val_if_fail (utils/fluid_sys.h:59).

Since the settings address is a valid one, I can't think of something else. Isn't it true that NULL pointers point to the address 0x00?

Am I forgetting something important ?

Comment: In a gdb session, what does "p *settings" do?

Comment: Hi, it gives me <incomplete type> just after running the new_fluid_settings function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the address before using it, using e.g. `printf("the settings are at %p\n", settings);`; and you can of course also add protection yourself:

```
if (settings != NULL)
{
  fluid_synth_setint(settings, "synth.polyphony", 128);
}
```

If it's the _new() call that is failing, you need to dig into why that could happen, of course.

It used to be that you had to manually initialize the glib library that FluidSynth seems to depend on, but that should no longer be necessary.

I had a brief look, and it seems it tries to initialize a mutex inside the settings object (to make it thread-safe, I assume), so it's possible that you need to add a call to `g_thread_init()` to your `main()`, before the call to `new_fluid_settings()`.

Comment: Hi, printing the address with %p gives a valid address.
However, GDB gives me an <incomplete type> to the settings structure. Adding g_thread_init() didn't solve the problem.

I'm quite curious to know what's going on. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: So after searching google for your pastebin, I was able to find the upstream bug report, which points here and marked as closed.  http://sourceforge.net/p/fluidsynth/tickets/104/.  The resolution was improper API usage caused by improper documentation (the upstream documentation is still incorrect).  Specifically, `fluid_synth_setint` should be `fluid_settings_setint`.  We have a downstream bug similar symptomatically here but seems to have a different cause: https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/issues/649